# How to Filter the data for the non working days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to filter the data for the non working days. For month December the non working days were the weekends and the days from 20 to 31.
Apperantly this `(DATEPART (DW, timestamp) IN (1,7 )) AND (DAY(timestamp) between '20' AND '31')` does not work since it returns me only the weekends between that range 20 to 31.

Comment: Change AND to OR and see what happens.

Comment: WoW. That was fast. It works. Thank you. Add it as a solution so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change AND to OR and see what happens.